# Why is the log of the mean of a draw from rlnorm different than the meanlog used to generate it?

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution

I'm trying to verify that I'm using rlnorm correctly. I made the following script

```
set.seed(123)
draw2 <- rlnorm(1000, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
draw2 <- tidyr::tibble(draw2)
log(mean(draw2$draw2))
```

I was expecting the log of the mean of the draws to be close to zero. Not 0.5138

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not to be stupid but 0.5138 *is* close to zero?

Comment: If a sample  has size 1000 with a mean of 0 and sd of 1 I would not say that something on the order of 0.5 was "close to 0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `rlnorm()` correctly (at least, there's no evidence that you're using it *wrong* ...)

`meanlog` corresponds to `mean(log(x))`, **not** `log(mean(x))`; this is due to [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) (briefly, that the mean of a nonlinear transformation $f$ of $x$, $\overline{f(x)}$,  is not the same as the transformed mean $f(\bar x)$).

```r
set.seed(123)
draw2 <- rlnorm(1000, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
mean(log(draw2))
## [1] 0.01612787
```

As a completely non-rigorous check, if we draw a much larger sample, `mean(log(x))` gets much closer to `meanlog` ...

```r
mean(log(rlnorm(1e6)))
## [1] -0.0005030754
```

Answer (score 4):

If $Y$ is [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, i.e. $Y = \exp(X)$ where $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ , then :

- $\mathbb E[Y]=\exp\left(\mu +\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)=\big(\exp(\sigma^2)-1\big)\exp(2\mu+\sigma^2)$
- $\mathbb E[\log(Y)]=\mathbb E[X] =\mu$ and $\text{Var}(\log( Y))=\text{Var}(X)=\sigma^2$
- $\log(\mathbb E[Y])=\mu +\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$ and $\log (\text{Var}(Y))=\text{Var}(X)=\sigma^2 +2\mu+ \log(\exp(\sigma^2)-1)$.

This is essentially what you have observed in your sample with $\mu=0, \sigma^2=1$

giving $\log(\mathbb E[Y])=\frac12$ together with some simulation noise.